# Stanford NER crash when called from Python NLTK

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I am trying to tag named entities using the Stanford NER. My code is very simple:

```
 from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
 st = StanfordNERTagger('stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', 
                        'stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar', 
                         encoding='utf-8')
 st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
```

However, I cannot get it to work. What I get back is a Java exception saying that:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed : [u'/usr/bin/java', '-mx1000m', '-cp', 'stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar', 
'edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier', '-loadClassifier', 
'stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', '-textFile', '/tmp/tmpq3u0oi', '-outputFormat', 'slashTags', '-tokenizerFactory', 
'edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer', 
'-tokenizerOptions', '"tokenizeNLs=false"']
```

Any idea of what could cause this crash? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using an older version of java. What is the output of `/usr/bin/java -version`? It should be at least Java 8.

Comment: I have openjdk version "1.8.0_212" but still i have this issue